# Solace publisher error handler in Spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace

Any reason why it contains **.errors** at the end of the topic name in @ServiceActivator as given in the below code snippet.  The documentation can be found in https://codelabs.solace.dev/codelabs/spring-cloud-stream-beyond/#9

Will it create a new error topic?

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="my/default/topic.errors")
public void handlePublishError(ErrorMessage message) {
    logger.warn("Message Publish Failed for: " + message);
    logger.info("Original Message: " + message.getOriginalMessage());
}
```

handlePublishError() method is called when the my/default/topic (topic) throws exceptions. My question is why we cannot keep `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="my/default/topic")` instead `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="my/default/topic.errors")` as my application publish the messages to my/default/topic

Answer (score 1):

That `@ServiceActivator`is handling errors on an error channel internal to Spring Cloud Stream. Basically it takes your existing channel and appends `.errors` to it. It was identified that this was not ideal and in v3.2.5 of Spring Cloud Stream they added the capability to setup your error handler via configuration. Checkout the "Spring Cloud Stream v3.2.5 or higher" section on that same page (in Section 9: Consumer Error Handling) or the latest Spring Cloud Stream reference guide.

Comment: As Marc stated, `.errors` is an internal convention used by the framework (not Solace specific). However as Marc pointed out we now provide a more idiomatic approach to error handling without exposing framework internals (e.g., channels)